# In Infinite Stairs, which Pet Items unlock the Explorer and the Ballerina?

Tags: infinite-stairs

I'm asking about the mobile game Infinite Stairs.

Under unlockable characters, there are two characters which are unlocked after you have used a certain pet enough so it gets a new item. You can see the picture of the items you need; however, you don't know which pet gets that item until after you buy the pet. So, my question is: does anyone know what items those pets belong to?

Answer (score -1):

Ballerina: Fully upgrade the cat and the rabbit.

Explorer: Got no clue. All of them?

Comment: Since posting I've bought every pet. Explorer is fully upgraded Dragon.

Answer (score -1):

Ballerina: cat and rabbit fully upgraded.
Explorer: dragon fully upgraded.

Answer (score -2):

Upgrade the dragon/dinosaur fully

Comment: Can you go into more detail? We try to persuade against the use of "half sentence answers". Maybe provide a picture of the dragon/dinosaur. Finding out if it is a dragon or a dinosaur 100% helps with how reliable your response will appear. Generally, single sentence answers get downvoted, even flagged for low quality. Paragraph answers, or answers that provide images / better quality content tend to be upvoted and recognised.